# When adding a Lightbox my dropdown menu shows up on top of the image

Tags: css, lightbox

I have been trying to set up a simple lightbox for my trip reports on my website.  I finally got Lightbox JS to work on my site (I had issues getting Lightbox 2 to load up) but I also use AllWebMenus and when you select the first lightboxed image the menus shows up on top of the photo.  Any idea how I can set it up that the menu does not show up on top of the image?

[Here is a link to my test page.](http://www.negative-g.com/test/joyland-amusement-park-2013-1.htm)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index: 9999` to the div `#lightbox`

Comment: Ok...looks like I have to add another div to my page as the photos and menu are in the same one.  Thanks a ton.